# About independence spread

Tags: pr.probability, real-algebraic-geometry

$A$, $B_{i}$ are some events.
If $A$, $B_{i}$ are independent $\forall i \in \mathbb N$ and $A \cap B_{1}, A \cap B_{2}, ..., A \cap B_{k}, ...$ are independent in aggregate, how to show, that $\forall B \in \sigma \{ B_{1}, ..., B_{k}, ...\}$ $A$ and $B$ are independent?
Events $A_1,..,A_n$ are called independent in the aggregate, if for any $1 \leq k \leq n$ and any set of different inter-indices $1 \leq i_1,...,i_k \leq n$ there is equality:
$$P(A_{i1} \cap...\cap A_{ik}) = P(A_{i1})...P(A_{ik})$$ Or we can say, that this events are pairwise independent, cause it follows from indepence in aggregage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conjecture is false. Indeed, consider the following example.

Let $B_1,B_2,A$ be subsets of the ground set $\{0,1\}^3$ defined as follows: 
\begin{align*}
B_1:=\{(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}, \\ 
B_2:=\{(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)\}, \\ 
A:=\{(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)\}.  
\end{align*}
Turn the ground set $\{0,1\}^3$ into a probability space by letting 
\begin{equation}
 \mathsf P(\{(i,j,k)\})=p(i,j,k) 
\end{equation}
for each $(i,j,k)\in\{0,1\}^3$, where 
\begin{align*}
p(0,0,0)&=a:=\frac{17-4 \sqrt{2}-12 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}8\approx0.270,\\
p(0,0,1)=p(0,1,0)=p(1,0,0)&=b:=\frac{-5+2\sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}8\approx0.111,\\
p(0,1,1)=p(1,0,1)=p(1,1,0)&=c:=\frac{1}{8}=0.125,\\
p(1,1,1)&=b:=\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}8\approx0.021. 
\end{align*}
This probability space is well defined, since 
$$\sum_{(i,j,k)\in\{0,1\}^3}p(i,j,k)=a+3b+3c+d=1.$$ 
Let also $B_3=B_4=\cdots=\varnothing$.

Then events $A$ and $B_i$ are independent for each $i=1,2,\dots$, and the events $A\cap B_1,A\cap B_2,\dots$ are independent. However, the events $A$ and $B_1\cap B_2$ are not independent.

---

*Comment:* The play here is pretty straightforward: The conditions that (i) $A$ and $B_i$ are independent for each $i=1,2$ and (ii) the events $A\cap B_1,A\cap B_2$ are independent impose only $2+1=3$ restrictions on the $8$ members of the family $\mathbf p:=\big(p(i,j,k)\big)_{(i,j,k)\in\{0,1\}^3}$ -- in addition to the restriction that the sum of those members be $1$. So, $8-3-1=4$ degrees of freedom are left, which prevents the independence of $A$ and $B_1\cap B_2$. The only (relative) difficulty here is to find a family $\mathbf p$ with positive members satisfying the conditions that (i) $A$ and $B_i$ are independent for each $i=1,2$, (ii) the events $A\cap B_1,A\cap B_2$ are independent, and (iii) the total of $\mathbf p$ is $1$; finding such a $\mathbf p$ amounts to finding a solution of a system of polynomial equations and inequalities. Here, to simplify that system of polynomial equations and inequalities, I actually reduced the $8$ degrees of freedom represented by the $8$ members of the family $\mathbf p$ to the just $4$ degrees of freedom represented by $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: What is, for example, p(0, 1, 0)? @losifPinelis

Comment: @Lisa : $p(0,1,0)=b=\frac{-5+2\sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}8\approx0.111237$, just as it is written in the answer. When one has the equality of two vectors/families, it just means that their corresponding coordinates/members are equal -- this is standard notation.

Comment: I have rewritten the answer in a slightly more elementary way.

Comment: Thank you. It very helped me. Can you please help to correct a condition that the statement became true? @losifPinelis

Comment: @Lisa : I am glad this was of help. Short of the obvious requirement that all the intersections (say) of the $B_i$'s be independent of $A$, I don't know at the moment of a clear way to fix the condition. However, I think it may indeed help to think about this problem in terms of degrees of freedom, as done in the comment part of my answer. Essentially, the problem is one of real algebraic geometry, and I have added the corresponding tag to your question.